# Setting timeout for new URL(...).text in Groovy/Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I use the following Groovy snippet to obtain the plain-text representation of an HTML-page in a Grails application:

```
String str = new URL("http://www.example.com/some/path")?.text?.decodeHTML()
```

Now I want to alter the code so that the request will timeout after 5 seconds (resulting in`str == null`). What is the easiest and most Groovy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to do it the old way, getting a URLConnection, setting the timeout on that object, then reading in the data through a Reader

This would be a good thing to add to Groovy though (imho), as it's something I could see myself needing at some point ;-)

<s>Maybe suggest it as a feature request on the JIRA?</s>

I've added it as a RFE on the Groovy JIRA

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3921

So hopefully we'll see it in a future version of Groovy...

Comment: +1: Very nice! And with a patch: http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/46210/URL.text-timout.patch

Comment: Wish I could think of a way of testing though (without requiring the test machine to have an internet connection, and without hammering some poor site each time someone runs the test) ;-)

Comment: Just an update, it has been released in Groovy. 
return new URL(url).getText([connectTimeout:500, readTimeout:5000]);

Answer (score 8):

I checked source code of groovy `2.1.8`, below code is available:

```
'http://www.google.com'.toURL().getText([connectTimeout: 2000, readTimeout: 3000])
```

---

The logic to process configuration map is located in method `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods#configuredInputStream`

```
private static InputStream configuredInputStream(Map parameters, URL url) throws IOException {
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    if (parameters != null) {
        if (parameters.containsKey("connectTimeout")) {
            connection.setConnectTimeout(DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(parameters.get("connectTimeout"), Integer.class));
        }
        if (parameters.containsKey("readTimeout")) {
            connection.setReadTimeout(DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(parameters.get("readTimeout"), Integer.class));
        }
        if (parameters.containsKey("useCaches")) {
            connection.setUseCaches(DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(parameters.get("useCaches"), Boolean.class));
        }
        if (parameters.containsKey("allowUserInteraction")) {
            connection.setAllowUserInteraction(DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(parameters.get("allowUserInteraction"), Boolean.class));
        }
        if (parameters.containsKey("requestProperties")) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, String> properties = (Map<String, String>) parameters.get("requestProperties");
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
                connection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

    }
    return connection.getInputStream();
}
```